# Auth0 wildcard login callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0, auth0-lock

I have this wildcard URL: `*.staging.company.com`

I'm using the `auth0-lock` npm package (using React) and pass a redirect URL when creating an instance of the auth0lock class. (for example, `test.staging.company.com`

when I'm login from my local environment indeed I'm redirecting to the correct URL. but when deploying into my staging environment, when I'm trying to login in `test.staging.company.com` auth0 is redirecting me to `staging.company.com`

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 doesn't support multi-level subdomain :(